# mono xsp4 Error 500 ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#, asp.net, macos, mono, xsp4

I installed mono version3.8 on mac. And I use xsp4 to run my asp.net web application. Then I got the following Error 500 . Please help me.

```
System.ArgumentNullException

Argument cannot be null.

Parameter name: type

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.

Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): mscorlib.

Exception stack trace:
  at System.Activator.CheckType (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, Boolean nonPublic) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinqDataSourceView+<ExecuteSelect>c__Iterator1.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.CreateItemsWithoutGroups (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewPagedDataSource dataSource, Boolean dataBinding, InsertItemPosition insertPosition, System.Collections.ArrayList keyArray) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.CreateChildControls (IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.PerformDataBinding (IEnumerable data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.InternalPerformDataBinding (IEnumerable data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnSelect (IEnumerable data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select (System.Web.UI.DataSourceSelectArguments selectArgs, System.Web.UI.DataSourceViewSelectCallback callBack) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.PerformSelect () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.CreateChildControls () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessLoadComplete () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.Page.InternalProcessRequest () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to use Object List instance of LinqDataSource. Now it's work.